# Empty directories are left over after uninstallation of package on higher version of RPM on LINUX

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

RPM version 4.8.0:

```
[root@sdl34815 x8664]# rpm -ivh tmfi1700-17.00.00.00.rpm
Preparing...         ########################################### [100%]
   1:tmfi1700        ########################################### [100%]
[root@sdl34815 x8664]# rpm -ev tmfi1700
[root@sdl34815 x8664]# ls /opt/manoj
ls: cannot access /opt/manoj: No such file or directory
```

RPM version 4.11.2:

```
sdl34817:/opt/BASE/Packages/Linux/x8664 # rpm -ivh tmfi1700-17.00.00.00.rpm
Preparing...                   ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:tmfi1700-17.00.00.00-1    ################################# [100%]
sdl34817:/opt/BASE/Packages/Linux/x8664 # rpm -ev tmfi1700
Preparing packages...
tmfi1700-17.00.00.00.rpm
sdl34817:/opt/BASE/Packages/Linux/x8664 # ls -R /opt/manoj
/opt/manoj:
client:
/opt/manoj/client:
17.00
/opt/manoj/client/17.00:
```

`rpm -qlvp tmfi1700-17.00.00.00.rpm` gives:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 24 2019 /opt/manoj
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 24 2019 /opt/manoj/client
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 24 2019 /opt/manoj/client/17.00
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 24 2019 /opt/manoj/client/17.00/lib64
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not due to the version of `rpm`. When packaging you need to decide which files and folders you will own. If you use:

```
%files
/opt/manoj/*
```

then your package will own all files under `/opt/manoj` but not the `/opt/manoj` directory itself. You should then use

```
%files
/opt/manoj
```

such that your package owns the `/opt/manoj` directory (and everything below recursively).

Comment: I mentioned these files in %files section  like below
%files

%defattr(0755,root,root,0755)

%dir %{prefix}/manoj
%dir %{prefix}/manoj/client

also it is working fine on RPM 4.8.0 but failing over 4.11.2

Comment: do the files `/opt/manoj/client/17.00` belong to your package? If they are created afterwards, `rpm` does not know that they belong to your package and won't erase them. I you want *future* files to belong to your package, you can use the `%ghost` directive.

Comment: yes those directories are belongs to my package. we mention these directories in %files section also

Comment: what does `rpm -qlvp tmfi1700-17.00.00.00.rpm` produce as output? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: sdl34817:/opt/INSTALL/Linux/x8664/tmfi # rpm -qlvp tmfi1700-17.00.00.00.rpm     

drwxr-xr-x    2 root    root                        0 Jan 24  2019 /opt/manoj
drwxr-xr-x    2 root    root                        0 Jan 24  2019 /opt/manoj/client
drwxr-xr-x    2 root    root                        0 Jan 24  2019 /opt/manoj/client/17.00
drwxr-xr-x    2 root    root                        0 Jan 24  2019 /opt/manoj/client/17.00/lib64

Comment: if you are sure that you use the exact same `rpm` file in both locations, than I'm quite out of ideas... very strange indeed.